# Frequency of 「気になる」 in this way

Tags: meaning, use-and-frequency

I came across this sentence:

> 「先月ケンカして　別れた　だけどあれだな　こう…弱ってる時　傍にいてくれたら　何でも許そうって　**気になる**よーな」

(The spaces marked where one line of the speech bubble ends)

The context is that two guys are talking about what they would do when they get really sick. After talking about how one of them wants to be treated by his girlfriend, he is asked whether they are still together and answers with the sentence above.

I was struggling with the meaning of 「気になる」in this sentence until I read this section from https://meaning-book.com/blog/20190122152525.html:

そして「気持ちになる」には、「その気持ちになる」という意味もあります。

例えば、「母親におだてられて、その『気になる』というフレーズを使う時、「母親のおだてに乗って、その気持ちになる」という意味があります。

「東大に行けると言われて『その気になる』」は、東大に行けるのではないかという気持ちになるという意味になります。
And I further found this definition: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%85%B6%E3%81%AE%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B/

I interpreted this って気になる as some kind of the same expression (if I am wrong about that, please correct me!) and wanted to ask how frequent the use of this 「気になる」 is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「気になる」in that sentence is not a standalone version of「気になる」, and「何でも許そうって気になる」is a block. The meaning is "to become to be willing to forgive everything".

This type of「気になる」is commonly used. Here are some examples:

- 「駅に行こうという気になった」: I became to be willing to go to the station.
- 「運動をはじめる気になった」: I became to be willing to start excercise.